# Polynomial Function with degree of 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The graph of a polynomial function of degree 4 is shown below.

Graph with real roots at $(-4,0)$ and $(2,0)$ and a $y$ intercept of $(0,-32)$

Explain why, of the four roots of the equation $f(x)=0$, two are real and two are complex.

I know that when there is a negative under a radical it produces complex roots, but I do not know how to explain why there are 2 real roots and 2 complex roots from just a graph.

Comment: Where is the graph? I ain't seen it yet.

Comment: You might want to add the graph. Also please use mathjax to format your questions. What do you know about polynomials? Have you learned the Fundamental theorem of Algebra? Please add information about what you have thought about.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial if degree $n$ will always have $n$ roots. If your graph of a 4th order polynomial shows 2 real roots, and you know that there are no more roots in the graph, then 2 are "missing". These two must be complex.

Also interesting is that if the coefficients of the polynomial are real then it's complex roots always appear in conjugate pairs. Therefore, again, if you know you have one complex root then you must have it's conjugate as well.

Algebraically, this is because the square root operation always produces a positive and a negative square root. For instance, $\sqrt{4} = \pm 2$ since either positive it negative 2, when squared, give you 4.

Comment: The graph shows two roots, but the graph window may simply too small to include two other roots. I.e. it may be that two roots are to the left or to the right of what the graph shows. So your first paragraph is not convincing.

Comment: Fair, but op had additional information. I'll try to edit the first paragraph